# Extracting only elements consisting of numbers from a list of strings

Tags: list

I have a list of string. How to get from a list only those elements that consist of only numbers.

```
ref_list=['hjusU676D','4567g76ds3','5543887269',6782yt76','234576722']
```

I would be grateful for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There ere many ways:

#using isdigit() or isnumeric()
Ex:

```
>>> ref_list=['hjusU676D','4567g76ds3','5543887269','6782yt76','234576722']
>>> [itm for itm in ref_list if itm.isdigit()]
['5543887269', '234576722']
>>>
```

#using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> [itm for itm in ref_list if re.match("^[0-9]+$", itm) ]
['5543887269', '234576722']
>>>
```